# How to stop XDM performing automatic downloads

Tags: 14.04, download-manager

I am using XDM (Xtreme Download Manager) as Download manager in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. It works well but sometimes it shows pop-ups to download some `mp3` or `wav` files from different sites, sometimes even when I open Google.

Today while using WebHTTrack, it opened such pop-ups for like 1000+ times and my laptops went to halt. Here's a snapshot of what it looks like.

[image: XDM Started multiple downloads at once]

I need some idea to stop such automatic downloads. I went through its settings, but could not find any settings to change or work with.

Answer (score 0):

Try the latest version.
This problem is fixed in version 4.7 for Linux
There is a checkbox added in the new download dialog, which can add the unwanted link to download ignore list.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do it by going through settings. In **Exceptions** I added Soundcloud but it still opened 100% of downloaded pop ups.

What worked was to disable it while using Soundcloud.

Comment: Please edit your answer and add some more details how to disable it. The answer must be useful in general (not only for the person asking, notice that the question is two years old).